# how can i create these columns in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset like the one below

```
Date           Price
2017-01-01     100
2017-01-02     187
2017-01-03     183
```

How can I create a column that gets the previous days info like

```
Date           Price    Previous_Days_Price
2017-01-01     100      NaN
2017-01-02     187      100
2017-01-03     183      187
```

Comment: Is possible some dates are missing, e.g `2017-01-01`, `2017-01-03`,`2017-01-04`,`2017-01-06`,`2017-01-07`?

Answer (score 1):

[`pandas.Series.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html) is what you want...

```
df['Price'].shift(1)
```